# Criar botão de busca igual ao do tema twentyfourteen

Tags: html, css

Preciso criar um botão de busca igual ao do tema [`twentyfourteen`](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen). Como posso fazer?

Comment: Qual botão exatamente @RafaelaBublitz?

Comment: O botão de search.

Comment: @RafaelaBublitz, seria isto que está a procurar? http://jsfiddle.net/9qnayd5u/

Comment: Não, TobyMosque. É bem como o exemplo abaixo do @SamuelDiogo. Mas não consigo implementá-lo em meu projeto.

Comment: Boa noite. Por favor, não edite o título para marcar como resolvido, selecione a resposta desejada e clique no botão de "check" abaixo dos pontos para escolher a correta, se você mesmo conseguiu resolver então você mesmo pode responder a sua pergunta e depois de dois dias você pode clicar no botão check. Obrigado por entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja como simples comandos de jquery e uso de css pode ajudar:

*Quando o usuário clicar no botão search, ele exibe o form de pesquisa..*

Veja um exemplo na prática:

```js
$( "#btn-search" ).click(function() {
  $("#search-wrapper").toggle();
  $("#search-wrapper").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.principal{
  width: 200px;
  }

#search-wrapper{
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  }

#txt-search{
  border: none;
  margin:5px 3px;
  width: 30%;

}
.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="principal">
<nav class="text-right">
 <a>home </a> | 
 <a id="btn-search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> search</a>
</nav>
<div id="search-wrapper">
 <form>
  search here: <input type="search" id="txt-search" name="txt-search">

 </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Viu que por default, o container do formulario de busca ficou declarado no css com **display: none**, logo ele só vai aparecer, se, o usuario clicar no botão, logo, a função **toggle()** alterna de *show ou hide* na medida que o usuário clica..

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Samuel, testei o código que me passou, mas por alguma razão, o Search nao está sendo um link e ao clicar não acontece nada. Coloquei: #btn-search { 
cursor: pointer;} mas mesmo assim, ao clicar, a ação não está funcionado. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Este é o link da página onde estou tentando inserir o código: http://oye-magazine.com/teste/back-to-the-past/

Comment: @RafaelaBublitz, coloque o script que chama o jquery no antes de tudo! main.js o sjquery que ainda não foi definido..

Comment: coloquei o código no http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYGXer e ele funciona normalmente. Mas quando coloco exatamente o mesmo código no wordpress, não funciona.

Comment: Olá @RafaelaBublitz, pelo que estou vendo via develper Tools do Chrome (tecla F12) em seu site, há 5 erros de javascript, e pelo que me parece, pode está relacionado a configuração ou a forma ao masonry está emplementado, uma vez com erro, ele não executa os comandos subsquentes... Depure o seu site identifique o que pode está acontecendo..bjs

Comment: Consegui resolver. Muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: @RafaelaBublitz Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode [marcá-la como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/74)? Ou até postar sua própria solução.